# MS Excel 2013 datagridview look

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, controls

Is there a way to achieve ms excel 2013 look like datagridview in visual studio ? Im interested if there is a way to use ms office libraries to use such a datagridview in my project. Because i'm building metro look like winforms appliacation and i could not achieve same effects with my datagridview, like cell sellection effect and slerping effect between one old and new selected cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView isn't really designed to mimic the spreadsheet capabilities of Excel and I don't think there are any built-in controls that do. You can probably extend it and add in the functionality you need but honestly, that's a lot of work. In fact, we found that it was cheaper to just buy a 3rd-party component that does what we need instead of trying to build our own. A few different components were discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144338/what-is-the-best-third-party-winforms-grid-for-net